# Office365 - List Users using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office365

I am able to retrieve all the users of Office365 with the help of PowerShell.

But I want to retrieve those users with the help of C# in Visual Studio without using the Azure AD like that.

And the users are from Office365 not from specific like Outlook or SharePoint.

So how to do this from my client directly using C# like in PowerShell?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to *StackOverflow*. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask a question. Also please do share something that you have tried so far, refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Happy to help, provided you have tried something so far.

Comment: removing code formatting not needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview). With an authenticated user you could get a [list of all users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users) within a tenant with a simple get request like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`.

To easier access this data from C# you can use the [corresponding NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph). The documentation about the usage and the code itself can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

Comment: provide some links to use this with C#

Comment: @saravananks: Added link to github repo which contains a usage description and further links about the usage.